# How to insert record in existing column using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
create table tbl1(rno int, name varchar(10))
insert into tbl1 values(101, 'neha')

alter table tbl1 add city varchar(10)
select * from tbl1
```

In this code, I am inserting a record into city column. I tried following code too, but this not proper code need help to add a record.

```
insert into tbl1 (city) 
    SELECT CITY  
    FROM tbl1  
    WHERE rno = 1

update tbl1 
set city = 'pune' 
where rno = 1;
```

2nd query is returning "0 records updated" ans.

Comment: from which column do you want to update city? is it in same table?

Comment: is there is any record found  for rno =1 ? i think no records found so the update not works...

Comment: The 2nd query isn't updating anything because your row in the table has `rno = 101` - not `rno = 1` ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row that you inserted into your table has `rno = 101` - so your `UPDATE` statement must look like this:

```
update tbl1 
set city = 'pune' 
where rno = 101;   -- use **101** here - not **1** !!
```